# Flutter button widget not working in Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am building a flutter web app, in which I have a Stack. In the Stack I have a Row with some buttons (along with other things). I made a seperate widget for the buttons. this is the code for that:

```
class UserPageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final String text;
  final onPressed;
  UserPageButton(this.width, this.text, this.onPressed);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 35,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100))),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                (states) => CustomColours.lightBlue)),
        child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: CustomColours.darkBlue, fontFamily: 'FuturaBold'),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have it in the Stack like this:

```
    Transform.translate(
                        offset: Offset(width / 8, height / 6),
                        child: Container(
                            width: width / 4,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                UserPageButton(width / 100 * 8, 'User Info',
                                    () {
                                  print('click');
                                }),
                                UserPageButton(
                                    width / 100 * 8, 'Match History', () {
                                  print('click');
                                }),
                                UserPageButton(
                                    width / 100 * 8, 'Invited People', () {
                                  print('click');
                                }),
                              ],
                            )),
                      ),
```

However, for some reason I can't press the buttons. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to add `final Function() onPressed;` rather than just `final onPressed;`? If it renders correctly and you just can't press it maybe it doesn't recognize the function. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot with the devtools enabled and showing gridlines?